# Facebook Android login- Passing details

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Well, I want the details to be passed when moving to a next activity. Details like name, email, profile pic, gender.

This does not happen somehow when the user is logged in. However, the details are sent when I am logging in for the first time.

*So I have two questions:*

**1) Why are the details not shown when the user is already logged in? Is there something that needs to be changed in the code?**

**2) Sometimes when I open the app after a long time it does not move to the `DetailsActivity` and opens the `MainActivity` with LoginButton with the text logout(so obviously it is still logged in yet returns null).**

*Have a look at my code:*

```
AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

**onCreate**

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email, public_profile"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email, public_profile"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            getUserDetails(loginResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //cancelled
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //handle error
        }
    });
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            accessToken = currentAccessToken;
        }
    };
    // If already logged in show the home view
    if (accessToken != null && Profile.getCurrentProfile()!=null) {
        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        databaseHelper.deleteAll();
    }
}


private void getUserDetails(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject json_object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("userProfile", json_object.toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
            });
    Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
    permission_param.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(120).height(120),gender");
    data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
    data_request.executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done this same.I did using webservice.
Pass the user details to backend and created response as retrieving the same user details back.Then I stored the response to sharedpreference.

```
     private void loginSuccess(JSONObject mJsonObject) {
    try {
        Snackbar.make(fbLoginButton, "Successfully Loged in!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        setSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.USER_ID, mJsonObject.getJSONObject(AppConstants.APIKeys.USER_DETAILS).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.ID));
        setSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.USER_NAME, mJsonObject.getJSONObject(AppConstants.APIKeys.USER_DETAILS).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.USER_NAME));
        setSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.USER_EMAIL, mJsonObject.getJSONObject(AppConstants.APIKeys.USER_DETAILS).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.EMAIL));
        setSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.LOGIN_STATUS, "true");
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
        this.finish();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Try this :)

Comment: So where have called loginSucess method? Could you share the code in detail?

Comment: In your onCompleted() do this

Answer (score 0):

In your onCompleted() do this

```
                       @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            Log.e("GraphResponse", "-------------" + response.toString());
                            Log.e("fb_json", "-------------" + object.toString());
                            try {

                                if (object.has("id")) {
                                    fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                }
                                if (object.has("name")) {
                                    userName = object.getString("name");
                                }
                                if (object.has("email")) {
                                    email = object.getString("email");
                                }
                                setSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.FB_ID, fb_id);

                                imageUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + object.getString("id") + "/picture?type=large";
                                Log.e("profileImage", imageUrl);
                                new WebserviceCall(LoginActivity.this, AppConstants.Methods.fbLOgin).execute(new String[]{email, fb_id, userName, getSharedPreference(AppConstants.SharedKey.DEVICE_ID), "", imageUrl});
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Then call webservice by passing fb_id,username,email etc and in the onPostexecute call  loginSuccess(mJsonObject);

Comment: Technically this might work by storing it to sharedpref. But if more than one user login is done or if a user has more than one account?

Comment: While this helps to save the details.. But I really don't wanna save details here using sharedpref. I am moving to a different activity where user can edit the details again received from facebook and then create a new profile and save it using SQLite.